# Custom Success Handler in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I followed the tutorial https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/ to integrate jwt to my application. I'm trying to add a custom successhandler to my application. Unfortunately, the successhandler is not triggering upon successful login request. I'm trying to return a user object instead of empty response with token in header. My handler is

```
@Component
public class AuthSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationUserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        UserDetails user = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        AuthInfo authInfo = new AuthInfo();
        authInfo.setUser(userRepository.findOneByUserName(user.getUsername()));
        authInfo.setToken(response.getHeader("Authentication"));
        response.getWriter().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(authInfo));
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setStatus(200);
    }

}
```

I have configured it in `WebSecurityConfigurer.configure()` as

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/public/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), securityConfig))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), securityConfig))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

@pvpkiran's solution didn't work. On debugging, I find that authenticationfilter is running twice and authorization filter is not triggering. Given below is the list of filters available in the application logs

```
Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  LogoutFilter
  JWTAuthenticationFilter
  JWTAuthorizationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Create a local method like this.

```
 public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter() {
        JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter filter = new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);
        return filter;
    }
```

And change your configure method like this

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/public/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

            http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Another point is it is better not to make your `AuthSuccessHandler` a bean (remove `@Component`) and create a object of AuthSucessHandler like this in Your security config.  Reason being, If you declare your AuthSuccessHandler as a bean, spring will scan it and add two SuccessHandlers(
 1. When it scans the bean,
 2. When you add it in your SecurityConfig.
)

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class JwtSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationUserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter() {
        JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter filter = new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        AuthSuccessHandler successHandler = new AuthSuccessHandler(userRepository, objectMapper):
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);
        return filter;
    }


protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/public/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

            http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Change your AuthSuccessHandler like this

```
public class AuthSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    private ApplicationUserRepository userRepository;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public AuthSuccessHandler(ApplicationUserRepository userRepository, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    ........
 }
```

Comment: This didn't work. It looks like there is something wrong with my configuration. I'll update the question.

Comment: it depends how you are testing

Comment: means? I'm using http post to the url '/login' to authenticate. It looks like authenticationFilter is authenticating twice and authorization is not triggering. Given below is the filter chain in the logs

Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  LogoutFilter
  JWTAuthenticationFilter
  JWTAuthorizationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]

Comment: i explained why would it happen twice

Comment: JWTAuthenticationFilter is not a component. When I remove it from configuration, then it won't trigger.